# Make tkinter Scale span it's full grid cell

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have a Tkinter `ttk.Scale` in a GUI. What I want to do is add some labels on the top or bottom (or side if its vertical) that show the values the user is selecting through. I have a minimum working example shown below.

My problem comes from the fact that I cannot figure out how to get the Scale to line up with the labels. It is set to span all the columns of the labels, but the Scale widget comes with a length keyword that automatically forces it to be 100 pixels in size. I can't know, a priori, what to set that length to and I can't figure out how to tell it to fill its grid space.

**Is there a way to tell the Scale to choose a length such that it fills its grid space?**

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

def show_values():
    print (w1.get())

def scaleFunc(val):
    scaleVal = float(w1.get())
    if int(scaleVal) != scaleVal:
        w1.set(round(float(val)))

root = tk.Tk()
for i,text in enumerate(['O','B','A','F','G','K','M','L']):
    ttk.Label(root, text = text).grid(row=0,column=i,padx=10)

w1 = ttk.Scale(root, to=7, command=scaleFunc, length=None)
w1.grid(row = 1, column = 0, columnspan = 8,ipadx=0)

ttk.Button(root, text='Show', command=show_values).grid(row=2,column=0,columnspan=8)

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I suppose I should have played around a bit more. It looks like the Scale widget listens to the `sticky` keyword in the grid manager.

```
w1 = ttk.Scale(root, to=7, command=scaleFunc, length=None)
w1.grid(row=1,column=0,columnspan=8,padx=(10,7),sticky='NSEW')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use either one of these solutions:

Solution 1: `w1.grid(row = 1, column = 0, columnspan=8, sticky='ew')`

Solution 2: `w1 = ttk.Scale(root, to=7, command=scaleFunc, length=250)`

The 1st solution is cleaner.

Comment: Thanks for this. The problem with solution 2 is that I can't know the necessary length to set it beforehand. This may be platform dependent and I'd prefer a versatile solution.

Comment: @zephyr Yes. That is the limitation of an explicit approach. That is why I said solution 1 is cleaner. The choice of solution really depends on how complex/simple your GUI have to be. :)